# Starting https connection with IP address and SNI

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, winapi, tls1.2

I'm using `WinHttpConnect` in order to establish an https connection between my windows app and a remote server. However, my server doesn't necessarily have DNS address so the connection is made with setting `pswzServerName` to raw IPV4 address.

```
WINHTTPAPI
HINTERNET
WINAPI
WinHttpConnect
(
    IN HINTERNET hSession,
    IN LPCWSTR pswzServerName,
    IN INTERNET_PORT nServerPort,
    IN DWORD dwReserved
);
```

Since there are several services on that remote server, I also need to specify the SNI (Server Name Indication) so that the TLS handshake will pass.

How can I pass the SNI separately from the IP address?

currently, the `client hello` packet contain SNI (see below) only if I open the connection with Url and the SNI matches that of the URL

[image]

In OpenSSL, there's a way to separate between SNI and URL, and I'm looking how to do so in windows API :

`OpenSSL s_client -servername appliance1 -connect 192.0.2.4:443`

EDIT:

Following the comments below, it seems like the method `InitializeSecurityContextA` should be called prior to `WinHttpConnect` with pszTargetName set as the requested server name.

However, what should I do with the other parameters if I wish to get their default value?

Here's my current implementation, How should I add the InitializeSecurityContextA in order to change the server name.

```
void connectFunction(std::string server/* can be ip address as well*/ , HINTERNET connectionHandle)
{

   sessionHandle = WinHttpOpen(
        NULL,
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        0
    );

    connectionHandle = WinHttpConnect(sessionHandle, server.c_str(), port, 0); 
    // this will trigger the TLS handshake, and I want to add SNI different than `server` param
```

Comment: if yourself handle ssl/tls encryption - in api `InitializeSecurityContext` we pass server name in *pszTargetName* (*string that uniquely identifies the target server. Schannel uses this value to verify the server certificate*). WinHttp internally call `InitializeSecurityContextW` when `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE` used but i not sure are possible pass *pszTargetName* here some how. not view such winhttp option

Comment: @RbMm, Thanks buddy ! perhaps you can show me minimal code sample of how to set the SNI using `InitializeSecurityContextW` prior to calling the connection method with the ip (the replacement of `WinHttpConnect`) ?

Comment: you can use *AcquireCredentialsHandleW -
 InitializeSecurityContextW - EncryptMessage -DecryptMessage* in case you yourself handle network data via socket. in case you use WinHttp or WinInet - this is internally used by this api. option here somehow pass parameters which will be used in this low level api, but for sni i not view such option

Comment: While it can technically work, HTTPS with IP addresses in URL is rare and should be avoided if possible. It needs a specific certificate, with a SAN entry being IPAddress which is different from the typical DNSname that DV certificate have. Do you have the proper certificate?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I also need it for the case where URL and server name aren't the same. why does those 2 values are expected to be coupled ?

Comment: @RbMm, perhaps do you know if `winINet` API has this capability of using different SNI and URL ?

Comment: @RbMm, do you think I can resolve the problem using dummy proxy server which will reside in my client and forward all packets from my unique SNI to the actual server IP/URL

Comment: After connect you pass an hostname or an IP address, plus a port, not an URL. IF you pass an hostname it is resolved to an IP address. This information is only used to know where to connect to at the TCP level, this happens before any TLS message. The servername parameter is fed inside the SNI extension during one TLS message in the handshake. This is to allow mass virtual TLS (HTTPS often) hosting. www.example.com and www.example.net can resolve to the same IP (so same connect parameter) but when you connect to them with TLS you need to specify the name for the server to know which you want.

Comment: On Windows 21 H1+ one could try `WINHTTP_OPTION_RESOLUTION_HOSTNAME` (haven't tried it myself)