# wininet https scraping error "You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port."

Tags: vb6, wininet

I'm web scraping some https website. This is my code.

```
hh.OpenHttp AddressOf InternetStatusCallback, "MY WEBSITE", "GET", 443, "/search/searchResult"
...
Private ctx As LongPtr
...
'OpenHttp Function
openRequestHandle = HttpOpenRequest(connectHandle, mMethod, mUrl, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNullString, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD Or INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, VarPtr(ctx))
```

And I got this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
<blockquote>Hint: <a href="MY WEBSITE"><b>MY WEBSITE</b></a></blockquote></p>
</body></html>
```

The website is not mine so I can't edit website.
I can just only edit my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your URL using "https" ?

Comment: yes, it is. ex) https://blahblah.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a secure connection flag when you call this:

```
void HttpOpenRequestA(
  HINTERNET hConnect,
  LPCSTR    lpszVerb,
  LPCSTR    lpszObjectName,
  LPCSTR    lpszVersion,
  LPCSTR    lpszReferrer,
  LPCSTR    *lplpszAcceptTypes,
  DWORD     dwFlags,
  DWORD_PTR dwContext
);
```

On MS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpopenrequesta

> INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE Uses secure transaction semantics. This
> translates to using Secure Sockets Layer/Private Communications
> Technology (SSL/PCT) and is only meaningful in HTTP requests.

And on Stack:

[How to send HTTPS request using WinInet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910463/how-to-send-https-request-using-wininet)

Comment: Thanks. so I use this now:
openRequestHandle = HttpOpenRequest(connectHandle, mMethod, mUrl, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNullString, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE Or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID Or INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID, 0)
But now, it doesn't work without any errors. Just infinity loading. What should I?

Comment: Why did you change the last parameter from `VarPtr(ctx)` to `0` ?

Comment: If I use VarPtr(ctx), then I get No Responding.