# HTTP Connection fails but returns an error code of 0

Tags: c++, https, mql4

I'm writing an HTTP requester for a library in MQL4. This is what I have so far:

```
#define INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG 0
#define INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT    1
#define INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI          0x00000200
#define INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE         0x00800000
#define INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE 0x04000000
#define INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP        3
#define INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTPS       6

HttpRequester::HttpRequester(const string verb, const string host, const string resource, 
   const int port, const bool secure, const string referrer = NULL) {
   m_ready = false;
   ResetLastError();
      
   // First, set the secure flag if we want a secure connection and define the service
   int service = INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP;
   int flags = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT | INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;
   if (secure) {
      flags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
      service = INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTPS;
   }
   
   // Next, report to Windows the user agent that we'll request HTTP data with. If this fails
   // then return an error
   m_open_handle = InternetOpenW(GetUserAgentString(), flags, NULL, NULL, 0);
   if (m_open_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_OPEN_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   // Now, attempt to create an intenrnet connection to the URL at the desired port;
   // if this fails then return an error
   m_session_handle = InternetConnectW(m_open_handle, host, port, "", "", service, flags, 1);
   if (m_session_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   // Finally, open the HTTP request with the session variable, verb and URL; if this fails
   // then log and return an error
   string accepts[];
   m_request_handle = HttpOpenRequestW(m_session_handle, verb, resource, NULL, referrer, 
      accepts, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI, 1);
   if (m_request_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_OPEN_REQUEST_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   m_ready = true;
}
```

When calling this code, the issue I'm having is that `InternetConnectW` returns a handle of 0, but `GetLastError` also returns 0. I have verified the host ("https://qh7g3o0ypc.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com") and port (443). What is going on here and how do I fix this?

Comment: Why you make non-functional object? Throw from constructor if construction failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It turns out that I was setting my flags and service improperly.

First, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/enabling-internet-functionality#setting-access-types), `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT` and `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG` conflict with each other. So, I removed `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT` to tell Windows that I would like to use the network settings stored in the registry.

Next, I looked at the Windows documentation, [here](https://INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT), and found out that, although `INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTPS` is defined, both HTTP and HTTPS requests are defined by the `INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP` service flag.

Finally, I was not including the `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag in the right place. I discovered, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910463/how-to-send-https-request-using-wininet), that this flag needs to be included on the call to `HttpOpenRequestW` and including it anywhere else would be redundant.

After making all these changes, my code looks like this:

```
HttpRequester::HttpRequester(const string verb, const string host, const string resource, 
   const int port, const bool secure, const string referrer = NULL) {
   m_ready = false;
   ResetLastError();
      
   // First, report to Windows the user agent that we'll request HTTP data with. If this fails
   // then return an error
   int flags = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;
   m_open_handle = InternetOpenW(GetUserAgentString(), flags, NULL, NULL, 0);
   if (m_open_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_OPEN_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   // Next, attempt to create an intenrnet connection to the URL at the desired port;
   // if this fails then return an error
   m_session_handle = InternetConnectW(m_open_handle, host, port, "", "", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, flags, 0);
   if (m_session_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_CONNECT_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   // Now, if we want a secure connection then add the secure flag to the connection
   if (secure) {
      flags |= INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
   }
   
   // Finally, open the HTTP request with the session variable, verb and URL; if this fails
   // then log and return an error
   string accepts[];
   m_request_handle = HttpOpenRequestW(m_session_handle, verb, resource, NULL, referrer, 
      accepts, flags, 0);
   if (m_request_handle == INTERNET_INVALID_HANDLE) {
      SetUserError(INTERNET_OPEN_REQUEST_FAILED_ERROR);
      return;
   }
   
   m_ready = true;
}
```